# spark ClassNotFoundException for a dependency

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, apache-spark

I added a third-party jar in some `spark` project. The issue is that `intelliJ` compiles and runs the code cleanly. But, when I submit it in the cluster with

```
./bin/spark-submit --master yarn --class myClass my.jar input output_files
```

I get

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gov/nih/nlm/nls/metamap/MetaMapApi
    at metamap.MetaProcess$2.call(MetaProcess.java:46)
    at metamap.MetaProcess$2.call(MetaProcess.java:28)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$toScalaFunction$1.apply(JavaPairRDD.scala:1027)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$mapValues$1$$anonfun$apply$41$$anonfun$apply$42.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:700)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$mapValues$1$$anonfun$apply$41$$anonfun$apply$42.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:700)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$6.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1109)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1108)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1108)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1285)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1116)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1095)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gov.nih.nlm.nls.metamap.MetaMapApi
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
```

I tried to add the `jar`'s third-party library specifying `setJar` to `SparkContext` instance but it didn't work. Then I added the dependency as a maven one but it didn't help much either. At last, I tried to specify the `--jars` command line option but with no success. Can someone help

Answer (score 1):

Here are options available along with the commands: -

1. Create a single fat jar file with all dependencies and use it with spark-submit command like shown below: -

   ```
   ./bin/spark-submit --class <MAIN-CLASS> --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster <PATH TO APP JAR FIlE>
   ```
2. Copy the jar file to *http://* or *FTP://* or *HDFS://* and then leverage the `SparkConf.setJars` and specify the full path for example - `SparkConf.setJars(Array("http://mydir/one.jar"))` and finally use the spark-submit command in same fashion with no changes: -

   ```
   ./bin/spark-submit --class <MAIN-CLASS> --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster <PATH TO APP JAR FILE>
   ```
3. Copy the jar file to *http://* or *FTP://* or *HDFS://* and then use the *spark-submit* command with *--jars* option: -

   ```
   ./bin/spark-submit --class <MAIN-CLASS> --jars <http://mydir/one.jar,http://mydir/two.jar> --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster <PATH TO APP JAR FILE>
   ```
4. Specify the variables `spark.driver.extraClassPath`and `spark.executor.extraClassPath` in *SPARK_HOME/spark-default.conf* file with the values as the full path of dpendent jar files and then use the same *spark-submit* command as used in #1

Depending upon the use case any one of the option will work. In case none works then you may need to recheck the provided dependencies to the *spark-submit* command

For more information refer here for [submitting the applcations](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html)

Comment: thank you I added `--jar` option but it did not work

Comment: can you also try the fat jar option and also update the question with the updated command with --jars option

Comment: I have created a single fat `jar` and I still get the exact same issue

Comment: Do we agree upon the fact that when setting `setJar` to SparkContext, I must add the third-party library ?

Comment: I am new to `spark` so I use `spark-submit`. I tried : `./bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client --addJars /_MetaMapApi.jar --jar my.jar --class metamap.MetaProces --args arg1 arg2` I had two problems : first, I get `Unknown/unsupported param List(arg1 arg2)` and if I delete `arg2`, I get `Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application application_1452690985153_0007 finished with failed status`

Comment: I have modified the answer with all options and way to provide the dependencies. One of the ways should work. Also there was mistake on my earlier comment, which I have deleted. Please try and let me know.

Comment: great I am going to check ;)