# Not able to connect to Cloud SQL using Java SocketFactory Library

Tags: java, scala, maven, apache-spark

I am trying to connect to Cloud SQL ( Mysql ) using my java code. I am getting the below error -

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create socket factory 'com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory' due to underlying exception: 
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory
```

Here is my code -

```
package utils
import java.sql.DriverManager
import java.sql.Connection
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
import entity.AnalyticFieldEntity
import compute.driver.AnalyticTools
import entity.ErrorHandlingEntity

object ScalaDbConnect {

    def getAnalyticBatchMap(toolId : Int, paramMap: Map[String, String]): Map[String, Int] = {
    val methodName = "getAnalyticBatchMap"
    val errorMode = paramMap.get("mode")+"("+paramMap.get("analyticSource")+")"

    val dbTuple = DbPropertiesReader.getDbProperties()


      val databaseName = dbTuple._3
      val instanceConnectionName = dbTuple._4
      val username= dbTuple._1
      val password= dbTuple._2


    var connection: Connection = null
    val analyticMap = collection.mutable.Map.empty[String, Int]
    try {
      //[START doc-example]
      val jdbcUrl = String.format(
        "jdbc:mysql://google/%s?cloudSqlInstance=%s&"
            + "socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory", databaseName, instanceConnectionName);

      println(jdbcUrl);
      //Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");
      val connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, username, password);
      println(connection);

    //[END doc-example]

      try 
      {

        val statement = connection.createStatement()
        val resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT omnitureColumnHeader.columnHeaderId, case when analyticFieldMap.isTag = 1 then concat(\"tag_\",analyticFieldMap.entityField) else  " +
        "analyticFieldMap.entityField  end as entityField FROM omnitureColumnHeader INNER JOIN analyticFieldMap ON " +
        "analyticFieldMap.analyticFieldBatch=omnitureColumnHeader.columnHeaderValue where analyticFieldMap.toolId = " + toolId);

        System.out.println("resultSet: 2" + statement);
        System.out.println("statement: 2" + resultSet);


        while (resultSet.next()) {

                    System.out.println("inside the content loop: 2");
          analyticMap += resultSet.getString("entityField") -> resultSet.getInt("columnHeaderId")


           }


        System.out.println("analyticMap: 2" + analyticMap);
    }
      catch
      {
         case _: Throwable => println("Got some other kind of exception")
      }


    } catch {
      case e: Exception =>
               val errorHandlingEntity = new ErrorHandlingEntity()
                  errorHandlingEntity.Mode=errorMode
                  errorHandlingEntity.Tool=paramMap.get("tool").toString()
                  errorHandlingEntity.Message="DB Connection Issue"
                  errorHandlingEntity.Trace=e.printStackTrace().toString()
                  errorHandlingEntity.Source = "Spark"
                  errorHandlingEntity.YarnAppId=paramMap.get("appID").toString()
                  errorHandlingEntity.MethodName=methodName
                  errorHandlingEntity.ReThrow = true
                  errorHandlingEntity.CurrentException=e

                  ErrorHandlingFramework.HandleException(errorHandlingEntity)
    }
    connection.close()

    analyticMap.toMap

  }
}
```

I have added the below details in my POM.XML

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is the complete POM.XML - https://pastebin.com/jvxSBZMX

I am trying to connect to Google Cloud SQL using my scala code and i am using the JAVA API(S). 
The issue i am facing indicates, i am not able to access the correct class for the connection.

Any help would be appreciated.

Looking forward for the solution.

Thanks,

Comment: as discussed in the GitHub issue, please include the snippet of your pom.xml file showing how you configured the assembly plugin. this looks like a general problem of a jar file not being packaged properly and likely not related to this library specifically.

Comment: Hello, Please find my POM.XML here -  https://pastebin.com/jvxSBZMX I have also checked the JAR by opening, and i can find the relative classes.

Comment: pom file looks correct to me. Since the pom file looks correct, it could be an issue with the way Spark loads/executes things. I'm not familiar with Spark so I can't help there.

Comment: if you do a search for classnotfoundexception on google or SO, you'll find some hits, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34856591/spark-classnotfoundexception-for-a-dependency

Comment: Thanks a lot, It solves my issue. It is strange spark is not able to resolve Dependent JARS although the jars are available in the maven Build. The issue resolves by giving missing Jars using --JARS extension.  Thanks

Comment: I have the same issue. I try to run a Spark application using the Cloud SQL Java socket factory on Google dataproc and I get the same exception. Neither bundling the socket factory in an assembly JAR nor specifying `--properties spark.jars.packages=com.google.cloud.sql:mysql-socket-factory:1.0.3` in the `gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark` call helps.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with how google cloud runs the maven Build.

It is not able to read the classes from the build so i passed those JAR Files with the extention --JARS .

This solves my issue.